# How can I stop draw with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to do my Paint-like using HTML 5 Canvas. I have to do two type of rectangle: filled and not filled. Here's how I did that:

```js
  function rectangle(state = false) {
    var first = [];
    var second = [];
    var click = 0;

    canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
      if (status == "rectangle") {
        if (click == 0) {
          first[0] = e.offsetX;
          first[1] = e.offsetY;
          click++;
        } else {
          second[0] = e.offsetX;
          second[1] = e.offsetY;
          if (state) {
            ctx.fillRect(
              first[0],
              first[1],
              second[0] - first[0],
              second[1] - first[1]
            );
          } else {
            ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeRect(
              first[0],
              first[1],
              second[0] - first[0],
              second[1] - first[1]
            );
          }
          click = 0;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is my call

```
//rectangle ;)
$("#fill").click(function() {
  $("#alert").text("fill Rectangle");
  status = "rectangle";
  rectangle(true);
});

$("#contour").click(function() {
  $("#alert").text("Rectangle");
  status = "rectangle";
  rectangle();
});
```

I have 2 buttons for choosing which type of rectangle the user wants.
When I click on `filled` I can draw my rectangle like I want but when I switch to `not filled`, it still draws by filling the rectangle. For drawing a not filled rectangle I have to press F5 and click first in `not filled`.

Comment: You're omitted the relevant part (how is `state` set) of your code.

Comment: i just added my call function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're adding a new event listener each time the fill checkbox is modified, but not removing the old listener. This means you're drawing both the outline-rect and the filled-rect. Instead, only add a single event listener and handle state indide it.

Additional notes:

- Firstly, you don't have to recreate a new context each click.
- Secondly, you have a lot of repeated code
- Thirdly, use `{x, y}` instead of `[x, y]` for future ease of modification.

```js
let shape = 'rectangle'
let fill = false;
let clicks = [], clickCount = 0;

let fillCheck = document.querySelector('input');
fillCheck.addEventListener('input', () => fill = fillCheck.checked);

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  if (shape == 'rectangle') {
    clicks[clickCount++] = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
    if (clickCount === 2) {
      ctx[fill ? 'fillRect' : 'strokeRect'](
        clicks[0].x,
        clicks[0].y,
        clicks[1].x - clicks[0].x,
        clicks[1].y - clicks[0].y);
      clickCount = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div><label><input type="checkbox">Fill?</label></div>
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you for your help and advice i will improve these points !